# is wso2 brs 1.2.2 compatible with developer studio 2.1?

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to follow the tutorial ([link](http://wso2.org/project/brs/1.2.2/docs/user_guide.html)) for brs 1.2.2 using developer studio 2.1.

The operation definition seems to be different.  This is from the tutorial:

```
<operation name="placeOrder">
    <with-param type="samples.userguide.PlaceOrder"/>
    <result>
        <element type="samples.userguide.OrderReject"/>
        <element type="samples.userguide.OrderAccept"/>
    </result>       
</operation>
```

However, developer studio is trying to create the operation definition like follows:

```
<operation name="placeOrder">
    <input namespace="" wrapperElementName=""/>
    <output wrapperElementName=""/>
</operation>
```

Is brs 1.2.2 compatible with developer studio 2.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, **brs 1.2.2** is not compatible with developer studio. It's **brs 2.0.0** version which is compatible with developer studio.

In that version what you would get will be similar to

```
<operation name="placeOrder">
    <input wrapperElementName="placeOrder" namespace="http://com.test/placeorder">
        <fact elementName="order" namespace="http://com.test/placeorder" type="samples.userguide.PlaceOrder"></fact>
    </input>
    <output wrapperElementName="placeOrderRespone" namespace="http://com.test/placeorder">
        <fact elementName="orderAccept" namespace="http://com.test/placeorder" type="samples.userguide.OrderAccept"></fact>
        <fact elementName="orderReject" namespace="http://com.test/placeorder" type="samples.userguide.OrderReject"></fact>
    </output>
</operation>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Do you know when brs 2.0.0 will be available?  I can only get 1.2.2 from the wso2.com page.

Comment: brs 2.0.0 is not yet released. But, you can get it from this tempory location http://builder1.us1.wso2.org/~carbon320/tmp/14-09-2012/brs/wso2brs-2.0.0.zip & http://builder1.us1.wso2.org/~carbon320/tmp/10-09-2012/wso2brs-2.0.0-docs.zip